# find $\frac{\partial f(u(x(t),y(t)),v(x(t),y(t)))}{\partial t} $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

how to find

$$\frac{d z}{d t} $$

where is $z=f(u(x(t),y(t)),v(x(t),y(t)))$

and if some one can give me some advice which make me deal more easy with this subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice for these types of questions is that you learn the [**multivariable chain rule**](http://mathinsight.org/chain_rule_multivariable_introduction) using the [**derivative matrix**](http://mathinsight.org/derivative_matrix).  This way, as long as you follow the matrix multiplication, you'll get the right answer.

In this case, we have three nested functions.  Define $g(x)=\langle u(x,y),v(x,y) \rangle$ and $h(t) =\langle x(t),y(t)\rangle$, and we can write the function as
$$
z=f(u(x(t),y(t)),v(x(t),y(t))) = f\circ g\circ h (t)
$$

Now, the matrix derivative chain-rule gives us the following:
$$
\begin{align}
D f\circ g\circ h (t) &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}\\
&= D (f\circ g\circ h)\\
&= (Df)(g\circ h(t))D (g\circ h) \\
& =(Df)(g\circ h(t))(D g)(h(t)) (Dh)\\
& = \nabla f(g\circ h(t)) \cdot 
\left(\frac{\partial u,v}{\partial x,y}
\begin{bmatrix}
x'(t)\\
y'(t)
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
\end{align}
$$

Where $\nabla$ is the gradient, $\cdot$ is the dot product, and $\frac{\partial u,v}{\partial x,y}$ is the Jacobian matrix, which is matrix multiplied by the matrix on its right.

I hope that helps.

When you expand that product, it looks like this:
$$
\frac{d f}{d t} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}
\left(
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}
\right) +
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}
\left(
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + 
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $z$ depends only on $t$, we have

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = \frac{dz}{dt}$,

and from there we just use the chain rule a few times.  First we note that

$\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \frac{du}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{dv}{dt}$,

then obtain $\frac{du}{dt}$ as

$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}$,

with a similar expression holding for $\frac{dv}{dt}$:

$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$.

From here on out, it's just algebra, recombining terms:

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} = \frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} (\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt})$

$= (\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial x})\frac{dx}{dt} + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y})\frac{dy}{dt}$.

You can't say much more without knowing the specific forms of $f(u, v)$, $u(x, y)$, $v(x, y)$, $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

Hope this clarifies.  Cheers.